# Python output to full screen like terminal based text editor

Tags: python, terminal

I am trying to build a program I can use to help me quickly categorize a large list of items. In order to do this I am hoping to be able to create a text based interface that allows me to quickly see what I need.

Although I can get input with input() and print with print() I am limited in building what I want to build because I cannot control the full terminal screen.

When I use vim/emacs/nano etc it causes my macOS terminal to fully display that program and the program doesn't seem to have to print() out a full page of content every time something changes. I am hoping to do something more like that but in Python and am not really sure what this is called or how to do it.

At a bare minimum it would be nice to be able to arrow through/highlight various lines of output.

Comment: The place to start is with the [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) interface.

Comment: text editor is complex tool - it may have to keep text as list of rows, count rows, remeber which row should be display at the top - and use `for`-loop to display only ie. 25 rows from list (if terminal has only 25 lines). Tools like curses may help to do similar thing but it still not simply. But maybe with [curses.textpad](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#module-curses.textpad) it will be simpler